# unable to perform form validation using bootstrap modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to perform form validation using bootstrap modals.The idea is to design a profile evaluator that helps the student in shortlisting his universities for applying to do masters in Overseas.My
idea is whenever the user clicks on submit it should open a modal 
showing the shortlisted universities.However,The end user cant click
submit with an empty form.So,I've added  form validators which says that  these fields are required.Even though,I've added those when i'm clicking 
the submit button it's opening the modal without showing "required  field".Below posted is my code.

```
  <body>`
 `<div class="demo">`
  <form action="profileEvaluator.php" method="post" class = "cmxform"   
   id  = "forrm"   required/>
  <fieldset>
  <label for="speed" id="uel" required>Select your Area</label>
  <select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option>Kansas</option>
  <option>Texas</option>
  <option selected="selected">California</option>
  </select>
   <label for="files" id="uel">Select your  field of Interest</label>
   <select name="files" id="files">
     <option value="jquery">Computer Science</option>
     <option value="jqueryui">Electrical Engineering</option>
     <option value = "jjjj">Mechanichal Engineering</option>
   </select>
   <label for="number" id="uel">Work Experience</label>
   <select name="number" id="number">
   <option >0</option>
   <option selected="selected">1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   </select>
   <label for ="number" id="uel">CGPA(or)GPA(or)Percentage:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"     
    placeholder="Example:70%,3/4,7.5/10" id="kanchu" required/>
   <label for ="number" id="uel">GRE:</label>
   <input type="text" name="gre" class="form-control"   
 placeholder="Example:300" id="kanchu" required/>
 <div id= 'eat-me' style='display:none'>
 <label for ="number" id="uel">Verbal:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:154"  
  id="ranju">
 <label for ="number" id="uel">Quant:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:148"  
  id="ranju">
 <label for ="number" id="uel">AWA:</label> 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:3.0"   
 id="ranju">
 </div>
<label for = "number"  id="uel" >Select Your Test</label>
<input type = "radio" name="test" value="TOEFL" id="vel"   
 required/>TOEFL</input>
<input type = "radio" name="test" value="IELTS" id="kel"   
 required/>IELTS</input>
</div>
<div id= 'show-me' style='display:none'>
<label for ="number" id="uel">IELTS:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:6.5"  
id="ranju" reuqired/>
</div>
<div id = 'touch-me' style= 'display:none'>
<label for ="number" id="uel">TOFEL:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example:300"   
 id="ranju" required/>
</div>
<div class = "input-group"  id="kkk" title="upload your Resume">
<input type="file" class="filestyle"   data-buttonName="btn-info"   
 data-input=false>
</div>
<div class = "input-group"   id="vvv" title="click this please!!">
<input type = "submit"  class = "btn btn-bitbucket"  data-toggle =    
"modal" href = "#myModel"> </input>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>


   <div class="bs-example">
   <div id="myModel" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
  `<div class="modal-header">
   `<button type="button" class="close" data- 
    dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">report</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
                 $k=include_once 'connect.php';

                 $query = "select*from ecommerce.Universities";
                 $exec = mysqli_query($db,$query);
                 if($exec)
                 {
                    $y = mysqli_fetch_array($exec);
                    echo $y['UniversityId'];
                  }
                 else {
                    echo "bye";
                     }



             ?>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
                  dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>     

 </body>
```